# Unit testing in multiple environments during a build

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, mstest, environment

Currently I have some unit tests that I would like to be executed during a build.  Problem is that we our software is going to be installed on a variety of systems, and the code that I'm testing is system dependent.

Seems like if I really want my unit tests run other environments, I would need some VMs running onto which I could dump my unit tests and dependencies, then run the tests and respond somehow.

If that's the case...  is there anything currently available to facilitate that?
If there's a better solution, what do you recommend?

These are VS2008/2010 solutions.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say what you best option is from here but SCVMM, VMWare Lab Manager, VS2010 Lab manager, are options to look at. You can definitely do what you want, the most feature rich environments tend to be on the expensive side though.

Answer (score 0):

[dejagnu](http://www.gnu.org/s/dejagnu) facilitates multi-platform testing and is pretty good at it, even though very sparsely documented. Getting it to work with a MS tool chain might be much integration work, though.